# Bootstrap button doesn't open modal

Tags: php, javascript, button, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a button:

```
<a data-target='#login' role='button' class='btn' data-toggle='modal'>Login</a>
```

That was working earlier, but now it won't open my modal.
Here is my modal:

```
<!-- Login Modal -->
<div id="login" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loginform" aria-hidden="true">

<!-- Header -->
<div class="modal-header">

  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h3>Welcome!</h3>

</div><!--/header -->

<!-- Body -->
<div class="modal-body">

  <form action="loginmanager.php" class="form-signin" method="post">

    <input name="username" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">"Remember me"</label>
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>

   </form>

</div><!--/.modal-body -->

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="modal-footer">

  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</a>

</div><!--/.modal-footer -->
```

What in the world did I do wrong? I looked at it multiple times and can't find why

Comment: Hard to see if there is no JavaScript ;)

Comment: Have you tried using href instead of data-target on your opening link?

Comment: What do you mean? It's just the js located: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html
And yes nathan

Comment: Add TB JS at the footer of the page.

Comment: It is at the bottom, I copied-pasted from the code

Comment: Is the closing #login div tag missing or just missing from the post?

Comment: I've just copy and paste your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KuTP5/) and looks fine.
Are you loading javascript and css correctly ?

Comment: Are you closing `<div id="login">` ?

Comment: Could it be more then one id="login" on the page?

Comment: Everything is being loaded correctly, I checked it.  I'm closing the <div id="login"> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing the inclusion of "bootstrap.js" (or, in the specific, the "bootstrap-modal.js")

Try to make your 'package' here (with the Modals) and to include the javascript in your page: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I corrupted my .js and .css files when I used find and replace.
Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

just remove the "hide" class from this line

```
<div id="login" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loginform" aria-hidden="true">
```